# Ember Data: Can't access model data from template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data, handlebars.js

So I've been beating my head against this for a few days now. I can't get my model data to render in the template at all. No errors are being thrown, and when I insert `{{model}}` or `{{controller}}` in the template, I get a reference to the DS and Ember objects, `<DS.RecordArray:ember411>`, and `<App.FamilyController:ember438>`, respectively.

Looking in the Ember Inspector, the Data tab shows my record loaded in families, and if I click through to the object reference, and into the members/posts field, it loads the members/posts in too... so the inspector at least seems to be getting the data correctly, but the template doesn't. Any help much appreciated.

*js/routes/family.js.coffee*

    `App.FamilyRoute = Ember.Route.extend
       model: -> 
            @store.find 'family'`

*js/templates/family.hbs*

    `<img {{bind-attr src=img}} alt="Profile">
    <h1>{{name}} Family</h1>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
    {{families}}
    {{controller}}`

*js/controllers/family.js.coffee*

    `App.FamilyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({})`

*js/models/family.js.coffee*

    `App.Family = DS.Model.extend
        name: DS.attr('string')
        description: DS.attr('string')
        img: DS.attr('string')
        members: DS.hasMany('member', {async: true})
        posts: DS.hasMany('post', {async: true})`

*json from API*

`{
    "families": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Weebleson",
        "description": "Bob, Jill, Jane, John and Spot.",
        "img": "/images/weebleson.jpg",
        "member_ids": [6, 5, 4],
        "post_ids": [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]
    }]
}`

`Ember      : 1.8.1
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.14.1
Handlebars : 1.0.0
jQuery     : 1.11.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.store.find` or `@store.find` in the coffeescript case returns *all* the models in the store. So, you are getting a **list back for your model** by default. It looks like there will be one family in that list.

If you want to display it in a list, you could use `{{#each family in families}}{{family.name}}{{/each}}`

To only get a certain ID in your `FamilyRoute`, you can use `@store.find('family', id)`. So an example would be `@store.find('family', 2)`. This would hit a different endpoint.

If you want to return the first result, you can use the promise that `find` returns:

`@store.find('family').then (family) -> family.get('firstObject')`

Comment: Thank you very much... Life can resume again! :P